# Convert pandas dataframe rows to list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with records as below, for all the rows succeeding `id` until there is a not null value for `id`, the value should get appended as a list.

```
[{'id': 'a', 'value': 1},
 {'id': nan, 'value': 2},
 {'id': nan, 'value': 3},
 {'id': 'b', 'value': 4},
 {'id': nan, 'value': 5},
 {'id': nan, 'value': 6},
 {'id': 'c', 'value': 7},
 {'id': nan, 'value': 8},
 {'id': nan, 'value': 9}]
```

I wan the output as,

```
id value
a  [1,2,3]
b  [4,5,6]
c  [7,8,9]
```

Tried method:

`df.groupby('id')['value'].agg(list)`

Comment: So what have you done so far to get this result? Where do you think the error is? What is the [mre] that you can provide that will help us start to help you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First forward filling missing values and then aggregate `list`s:

```
df = df.groupby(df['id'].ffill())['value'].agg(list).reset_index()
print (df)
  id      value
0  a  [1, 2, 3]
1  b  [4, 5, 6]
2  c  [7, 8, 9]
```